# Check if a user is online mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC4 and what I want to be able to do is to check the status of a user's friend to see whether they are online or not for chat purposes.  I have explored the `WebSecurity` and `MEmebership` classes but cannot see any functionality within these.  Do I have to do something with getting the sessions from the IIS server?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'll want to use a database to store a member's last visited time and have AJAX calls from pages to say they still have the page open. Then if the visit time is within 5 minutes or so, say they're online. Anything more "live" than that will be more complicated.

Comment: Shame, this is not implemented as a part of MVC4

Comment: I'm unsure if MVC4 has functionality for this. Maybe with a Nuget package there is already built for you, but that's how I'd do it.

Comment: Yes OK, thank you, seem quite intensive

Comment: If you're not using multiple servers (web farm) you can handle it using Session or MemoryCache with slide expiration.

Answer (score 3):

There is [MembershipUser.IsOnline Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.isonline(v=vs.110).aspx) but if this is not useful you can use signlR to check the current status and may be store it somewhere.
Else you can do an ajax call every few minutes to check user status and also store it somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution I am suggesting you is to create a global filter that populates `LastActionTime` field of every user and then use this field to determine whether the user is online or not:

First create a new property of type `DateTime?` called `LastActionTime` in your `User` class in case you are using Code-First approach. In case you are using Database-First approach just add nullable DateTime column in you `Users` table and update your local model.

```
public class User
{
    // ...
    public DateTime? LastActionTime { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

Then create a new class called `LogUserActionTimeFilter` and implement it's `OnActionExecuting` and `OnActionExecuted` method. If you have any services or DbContexts, initialize them in the constructor of the class.

```
public class LogUserActionTimeFilter : IActionFilter
{
    private readonly IUserAuthService userAuthService;

    public LogAdminRequestFilter()
        : this(new UserAuthService())
    {
    }

    public LogAdminRequestFilter(IUserAuthService userAuthService)
    {
        this.userAuthService = userAuthService;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        this.userAuthService.SaveCurrentTimeAsLastActionTime(
            filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
    }
}
```

The `SaveCurrentTimeAsLastActionTime` method just sets `LastActionTime` to `DateTime.Now` of the given user and saves changes. It should be easy to implement.

When done with the filter you can apply it to specific actions, controllers (e.g. in the chat only) or globaly:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new LogUserActionTimeFilter());
    }
}
```

When you need to determine if a user is online or not just check its `LastActionTime` column/property and if it is less than 5 minutes (for example) before `DateTime.Now` then the user may be considered online.